# Connecting with a mobile phone over a 2-3 ft distance, and not beyond that

Tags: rf, signal, telephone, mobile

I have a device that I want to connect with a mobile phone at 2-4 ft, but not if the phone is further away than that. What signal or design can I use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no technology that I'm aware of that cheaply achieves localization accuracy to that degree, and if you went by channel properties, things get pretty expensive pretty fast as well. The problem here is that the only unfakeable property of a channel not allowed to be longer than a specific length is the speed of light, and that means that in your range, both sides would need to be able to exchange data with latencies sufficiently below 1 ns, which is a technical challenge.

So, I think there's simply no way that your phone (not some specialized equipment) could solve that.

This question regularly comes up when people try to do safe local pairings of devices.

Either you close in closer and use passive RFID Tags whose reaction the reader could time sufficiently accurately (again, phones can't), or you relax the constraint and assume Bluetooth pairing with a pin to be secure enough in most contexts.

There's few functional devices that actually apply the heavily-subsidized research into *physical layer security*, and even fewer that apply that to *authentication*, so I'm really afraid you're going for technology that simply doesn't exist so far.

Comment: Actually, with that range, it's physically impossible to exchange data at latencies below 1 ns, because the maximum length is greater than 1 light-nanosecond.

Comment: Yes, but to prove you're 1m away and not 1.5m, you need a responder that reacts fast enough so that even if someone builds a faster responder, you can subtract the maximum allowable amount of flight time and be sure you haven't left the allowed range significantly.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about time-of-flight distance sensing; that's possible, you just do your timing with different systems than the communication.

Comment: Yes, but still two problems: you must be able to verify that the system that communicates is the same that reacts to the tof sensing. That's as far as I know unsolved for the case where you separate the fast transponder (or just reflector) from the communicating part. And you still need the time it takes  the transponding part to react very low.

Comment: This really gets into physical layer security pretty quickly, doesn't it? How can I prove that I saw that short channel, and it was not someone else who you used for timing and now I'm just hijacking the comms exchange?